# Get form submit button value attribute value in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I basically want to have functionality like [this example at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_value2)

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
Choose your favorite subject:
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="fav_HTML">HTML</button>
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="fav_CSS">CSS</button>
</form>
```

except in Angular, where if a user clicks either button, I can in my controller see if he clicked the `HTML` or `CSS` button.

What I've tried so far is this (view with my version of finding out if user clicked `agree` or `decline`)

```
<form name="agrCtrl.agreement" ng-submit="agrCtrl.submit()">
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="agree">
        Agree
    </button>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="decline">
        Decline
    </button>
</form>
```

and controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
.controller('AgreementController', AgreementController);

function AgreementController() {
  var agrCtrl = this;

  agrCtrl.submit = submit;

  //////////

  function submit() {
    console.log(agrCtrl.agreement);
  }
}
```

however, when I log the `agrCtrl.agreement` I cannot find anything pointing to the `agree` or `decline` value of the `value` attribute.

I also tried changing it to `ng-value` it had no effect on this test.

I also know I could skip the form and just use `ng-click` on either button, which I think I will do, but I still think this poses an interesting question, since according to the W3Schools example, this looks possible.

Comment: have `ng-click` on each button that sets some value in your controller's scope. `ng-click="this.btn = 'agree'"`, dont remember if that syntax is valid though.

Comment: thank you, however I already stated in my last paragraph that I know this is possible, but want to see if the other method is possible (the one I'm asking about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form, the submit button you use to do it is successful and its name=value pair will be submitted, in the HTTP request, with the rest of the form data (which is how the example you link to works).

When you first a client side submit event, there is no information about which submit button was used to trigger the event available.

So you have to do this:

> I also know I could skip the form and just use ng-click on either button

To solve a similar problem (in an environment where I had jQuery but not Angular, although the principles are the same) I did this:

```
    // Add hidden inputs when a button is clicked so that we can maintain the name/value despite GA tracking interference
    $f.on("click", "button, [type=submit]", function(event) {
        // Get the existing tracker
        var $tracker = $f.find("input[type=hidden].selectedsubmitbutton");
        if (!$tracker.length) {
            // Create a new tracker if we can't find one
            $tracker = $("<input />")
                        .attr("type", "hidden")
                        .addClass("selectedsubmitbutton")
                        .appendTo($f);
        }
        // Update the tracker with the data from the submit button that was just clicked
        $tracker
            .attr('name', this.name)
            .val(this.value);
    });
```

… since hidden inputs are always successful and appear in the form, they are available to the server and to any JS which can access the form object.

Comment: then how do you explain the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_value2) example?

Comment: @Matthias — they use server side code. I explained it in the first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: oh I see. So they use the traditional form functionality at w3schools which angular cancels to do their thing. Meaning I can't recreate that example and have to do `ng-click` like you said.

Comment: @Fissio angular does cancel the default form submit actually (with `ng-submit`). To avoid refreshing the page like is done with traditional forms.

Comment: Quentin thank you. This was a misunderstanding on my part, not realizing I wanted to do this solely using frontend, but w3schools was using backend functionality.